# P2002 DPF code intermittent engine light F-350

Tags: ford, f-350, diesel-particulate-filter

The check engine light comes on and goes off on my 2008 F-350 6.4L The truck runs and tows (29' Toy Hauler camper) fine.  I mainly drive it long distances and not around town.  Getting around 11 mpg.  Is it likely that the DPF is clogged when the truck is operating properly?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How often does the light come on and go off? If it comes on when driving and you then drive 30 or 40 minutes does it go off?

Comment: I can drive it 100's of miles without the light on and then it comes one for a day or so.  It seems to come one when I stop at a rest area.  It did have a problem with the fan clutch which was repaired and the shop ran it through a forced regen for the P2002 code.  Then I drove it about 300 miles with no light, got home and drove a short distance and the light came on with P2002 DPF code.

Comment: I took it to the Ford dealer to have the control module checked and reprogrammed and they said it has to have the DPF replaced because the module says so.  Shouldn't they have run a pressure test on it?